# What is the benefit of SSR: true prop with dynamic imports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

What is a difference between dynamic imported component with `ssr: true`:

```
const DynamicButton = dynamic(() => import('./Button').then((mod) => mod.Button), {
  ssr: true,
});
```

and just normal component import:

```
import { Button } from './Button';
```

- What is the benefit of one over the other?
- Where do we put load on?
- For scenario below (JSX example), if `showButton` is `false`, did we still load `DynamicButton` and where?

---

```
// jsx
return showButton && <DynamicButton />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### Regular import

When using a regular component import, Next.js bundles the component's code together with the rest of the components for a given route. This usually means you end up with a big chunk containing all the components code for each route.

##### `next/dynamic` with `ssr: true`

When using `next/dynamic` with `ssr: true`, Next.js splits the component's code into a separate chunk (code splitting) and loads that chunk separately (lazy loading).

This means that for the scenario that you described:

```js
return showButton && <DynamicButton />
```

The `DynamicButton` component only gets loaded when `showButton` is truthy. This has the benefit of reducing the amount of JavaScript that's loaded on initial page load.

##### `next/dynamic` with `ssr: false`

When using `next/dynamic` with `ssr: false`, all the above benefits of the dynamic import also apply. However, the component's code will not get preloaded on the server and will only run on the client. This is typically useful when the component includes a library or API that only works in the browser.

Comment: I have a question about the ssr: true option, let's say we set ssr: true but then call the component like  return <DynamicButton /> (without the condition), by doing this, will it become the same as the regular import?

Comment: @MuhammadOsama In that scenario, the only difference is that `DynamicButton` gets loaded in a separate chunk, but will still load when the page loads too.

Comment: Exactly as I thought, thanks for clearing this out. One more question, do you think using dynamic imports like such (without condition) should have some positive effect? As I've always believed that dynamic imports should only be used if they're being loaded conditionalliy for example a modal, which is not shown initially but later at some time and some users might not even open a popup

Comment: @MuhammadOsama You're right, that's what I think as well. I don't see much benefit of dynamically loading if it's not conditional.